# Show $\ln x = x^3 + \sqrt x − 5$ has at least one real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does anyone know how to prove that $\ln x = x^3 + \sqrt x − 5$ has at least one real root? It’s my first time to encounter the equation that starts with $\ln x = \dots$

Comment: Hint: Intermediate Value Theorem. There is no need to explicitly find such $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $f(x) = \ln x - x^3 - \sqrt x +5 $. Then $f$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$, $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)= -\infty$ and $f(1)=3>0$. By [the intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), $f$ has at least on root in $(0, 1)$.

More specifically, $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)= -\infty$ so there exists $a \in (0, 1)$ such that $f(a)<0$. Now apply the theorem for the interval $[a, 1]$. Since $f(a)<0<f(1)$, there exists $c \in (a, 1)$ such that $f(c)=0$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The function : $f(x) = \ln x  - x^3 - \sqrt{x} + 5 $ on $(e^{-10},1)$ is continuous and has $f(e^{-10}) < -10 + 5 = -5 < 0, f(1) = 3 > 0$. Then by the IVT in calculus it has at least one zero in the above interval hence at least a zero in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Any special reason for using $e^{-10}$ instead of $e^{-5}$?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with an indeterminate form, we can consider the value of $f(x)=\ln x-x^3-\sqrt x+5$ for $x=e$.

Then $f(e)=\ln e - e^3-\sqrt e + 5 <1-2^3-0+5=-2$.

Using $f(1)=\ln 1-1^3-\sqrt1+5=3$ and the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (1,e)$.